# Localstorage does not work on local webpage: security error

Tags: javascript, brave

When using my webpage (http://localhost/mypage.html) accessing localStorage issues a security error:

*Uncaught DOMException: Failed to read the 'localStorage' property from 'Window': Access is denied for this document.*

It is just a simple line

```
res = localStorage.getItem(name);
```

and even

```
console.log(localStorage);
```

issues the same error.

But it is a LOCAL site, so no cross domains are used.

What goes wrong here ?

Comment: Which browser are you using?

Comment: Have you read this https://www.chromium.org/for-testers/bug-reporting-guidelines/uncaught-securityerror-failed-to-read-the-localstorage-property-from-window-access-is-denied-for-this-document ?

Comment: I forgot to specify it.

Comment: Brave.
In FF, Chrome and Safari on macOS it does work.
But in Chrome for Android (desktop mode) not.

Comment: check that your version of chrome for android match the requirement for local storage on [canIuse](https://caniuse.com/#search=localStorage) website

Answer (score 1):

This problem is related to a Chromium bug which is now fixed. See https://community.brave.com/t/html5-localstorage/100843

You can check if your current version is affected with this JSFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/6sm54/2/

```
function lsTest(){ 
    var test = 'test';
    try {
      localStorage.setItem(test, test);
      localStorage.removeItem(test);
      return true;
    } catch(e) {
      return false;
    }
}
```